# debugging the toggle switch css?

Tags: css

guys i'm struggling these days with understanding the toggle switch code i found this on google and i'm trying to understand the code to strengthen my css skills
please help me and thank you in advance.

**1.why this person put the transition declaration when the toggle switcher can work without it ?**

**2.why we should use the adjacent combinator and not any other combinator? i tried the descendant combinator and it doesn't work i wanna know why?**

**this is the HTML code:**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" dir="ltr">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="test.css">
    <title></title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <label class="switch">
  <input type="checkbox" class="input">
  <span class="slider"></span>
</label>
  </body>
</html>
```

**and this is the CSS:**

```
    .switch {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  width: 60px;
  height: 34px;
}

.switch .input {
  opacity: 0;
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
}

.slider {
  position: absolute;
  cursor: pointer;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  background-color: #ccc;
 -webkit-transition: .4s; 
  transition: .4s;*/
}

.slider:before {
  position: absolute;
  content: "";
  height: 26px;
  width: 26px;
  left: 4px;
  bottom: 4px;
  background-color: white;
   **i understand that here it's necessary for the cool effect of the transition but above i don't see why we used it?** 

-webkit-transition: .4s; 
      transition: .4s;
    }
.input:checked + .slider {

  background-color: #2196F3;
}

.input:focus + .slider {
  box-shadow: 0 0 1px #2196F3;
}

.input:checked + .slider:before {
  transform: translateX(26px);
}
```

Comment: The transition is for animation, it isn't needed, as you indicated. The adjacent combinator is used because the slider is, well, adjacent to the input.

Comment: If the switch was made a descendant of the input the html would not be valid. This may be why the designer has structured it this way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**1. The transition on the toggle**
That's totally up to the person designing the site. If the code works fine without it then you're fine to remove it if that look/feel doesn't appeal to you.

**2. Why the adjacent?**
In this case using the adjacent combinator ensures that only the `.input` that belongs to `.switch` is going to be impacted by whatever styles are declared. This would be done in case the `.input` class is going to be called many other times throughout the page. The other instances of it would all retain the default styles for that class while the one within the `.switch` class would have the unique styles.

Answer (score 1):

**1.** The `transition` declaration for `.slider` is used to transition its `background-color` property, it's a subtle effect that you may have not noticed.

**2.** The descendant combinator couldn't indeed work in that case as the `.slider` span is not a descendant of the checkbox, but adjacent to it. Another selector you could use in that case instead is the sibling `~` selector, with a similar result.